# How can I manipulate a string in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Currently I'm working in a project with flutter, but I realize there is a need in the management of the variables I'm using.

Basically I want to delete the last character of a string I'm concatenating, something like this:

```
string varString = 'My text'
```

And with the help of some method or function, the result I get:

```
'My tex'
```

Am I clear about it? I'm looking for some way which helps me to 'pop' the last character of a text (like pop function in javascript)

Is there something like that? I search in the Dart docs, but I didn't find anything about it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a substring, like this:

```dart
string.substring(0, string.length - 1)
```

If you need the last character before popping, you can do this:

```
string[string.length - 1]
```

Strings in dart are immutable, so the only way to do the operation you are describing is by constructing a new instance of a string, as described above.

Comment: What if I need to remove that character completely? If the data is immutable... how can I replace into the 'original' variable?

Comment: Can I assign it like: 'string = string.substring(...)' ?

Comment: By the way, thanks a lot for your comment

Comment: You would need to do it the same way you would replace an integer, or any other immutable value. You would find the place it's referenced, and assign it the new value. For example, if it's in a local variable called `string`, you would modify it like `string = string.substring(0, string.length - 1)`. If it's in an array, you might do `array[index] = array[index].substring(0, array[index].length - 1)`. Edit: the thing you suggested would work.

Comment: substring is definitely the way to go!

Answer (score 1):

```
  var str = 'My text';

  var newStr = (str.split('')..removeLast()).join();
  print(newStr);
```

Another way:

```
  var newStr2 = str.replaceFirst(RegExp(r'.$') , '');
  print(newStr2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment... I try this way